# if in else Array formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table and I am dynamically concatenating few column values.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQUG4TmFTKghV8r6Gg3EilLx6zyuTkrNfnCatRVWp_U/edit#gid=0

I want to concatenate all rows

1. columns C, H, I and J when K is empty
2. columns C, H, I and K when J and K are filled

I have used the below formula which currently concatenates columns C, H, I, J and K

The formula used is

```
= ArrayFormula(query(byrow(
{lookup(row(C5:C),row(C5:C)/(C5:C<>""),C5:C),H5:H,I5:I,J5:K},
lambda(r,textjoin("-",1,r))),
"select Col1 limit "&-1+max(J5:K<>"",row(J5:K))))
```

Comment: What would be your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQUG4TmFTKghV8r6Gg3EilLx6zyuTkrNfnCatRVWp_U/edit#gid=906986568):

```
=map(scan(,C5:C,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),H5:H,I5:I,J5:J,K5:K,lambda(c,h,i,j,k,if(and(j="",k=""),,
       ifs(k="",textjoin("-",1,{c,h,i,j}),len(j)*len(k),textjoin("-",1,{c,h,i,k}),1,))))
```

[image]

***Updated formula***:

```
=MAP(scan(,C5:C,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),H5:H,I5:I,J5:J,K5:K,lambda(c,h,i,j,k,if(and(j="",k=""),,
       ifs(and(counta({h,i})<>2,counta({j,k})<>2),,
           and(counta({h,i})<>2,counta({j,k})=2),textjoin("-",1,{c,h,i,j,k}),
           k<>"",textjoin("-",1,{c,h,i,k}),
           j<>"",textjoin("-",1,{c,h,i,j})))))
```

Comment: this does not cover the case where when  col J is empty but an entry in col K. the concatenation in tis case should happen on col C-col H - col I - col K

Comment: Can you  enter a few of those (non-working) scenarios in your sample sheet and also enter the expected output for them (*manually*) so that it gives a clear picture to amend the formula

Comment: I have updated, please check the column "Expected Output"

Comment: You are a rockstar! @rockinfreakshow, Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow, I have some more uses cases here and was wondering if they can also be updated using the formula you had helped here with. The same spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQUG4TmFTKghV8r6Gg3EilLx6zyuTkrNfnCatRVWp_U/edit#gid=0 

I have updated rows 21 to 31 with the cases. Please help!

Comment: Formulas **do not** recognise OR have access to cell formatting alike strike-through. Try with Apps Script folks by posting a question under `[google-apps-script]` tag

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow, please help me on this - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQUG4TmFTKghV8r6Gg3EilLx6zyuTkrNfnCatRVWp_U/edit#gid=189998773 with ```column P```.
Please!

Comment: I did try to tweak the formula that you provided earlier to use in this case as ```=MAP(scan(,D5:D,H5:H,lambda(a,b,d,if(or(a="",b="",d="",and(e="",f="")),,if(f<>"",f,e)&" "&a&" "&b&" "&c))),D5:D,H5:H,I5:I,J5:J,K5:K,lambda(a,b,c,e,f,if(or(a="",b="",c="",and(e="",f="")),,if(f<>"",f,e)&" "&a&" "&b&" "&c)))``` but hit an error of formula parse